# Natbib does not show author year but author numeric

Tags: natbib

```
\documentclass{elsarticle} 
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
Artificial reefs (\citet{seaman2013artificial}).

\bibliographystyle{plainnat} %
\bibliography{ref_ar1}

\end{document}
```

where my `ref_ar1` contains

```
@book{seaman2013artificial,
  title={Artificial habitats for marine and freshwater fisheries},
  author={Seaman Jr, William},
  year={2013},
  publisher={Academic Press}
}
```

This gives me result as follows, but I want to have author year, i.e., Seaman Jr (2013) instead of numerics. Could someone give me a hand? Many thanks in advance.

> Artificial reefs (Seaman Jr [1]). [1] William Seaman Jr. Artificial
>   habitats for marine and freshwater fisheries. Academic Press, 2013.

Comment: Have you tried setting the citation style? Here are some links about that: https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Natbib_citation_styles and: http://merkel.zoneo.net/Latex/natbib.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\setcitestyle{authoryear,open={(},close={)}}

\begin{document}

Artificial reefs (\citet{seaman2013artificial}).

\bibliography{refs} 
\end{document}
```

It gives this result:

[image: Result of code provided]

**Note**: `\bibliography{refs}` was used because I named my `.bib` file "refs.bib" -- which contained only the reference you provided

Some helpful sources:

- [Citation Styles](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Natbib_citation_styles)
- [Bibliography Management](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management)

Comment: @Sissi - In response to your comment about `{elsarticle}` I'm not exactly sure what else you need help with. The code I provided in my answer gives the result that I provided an image of. If you give me more information, perhaps I can help you further. If this is no longer an issue or if I've given you as much help as you've needed, I'd ask that you please press the check mark next to my answer to accept it. That will give me credit for having provided you with the best answer, and I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I am new to the site. My apologies for the late response. I have now pressed the check mark. b.t.w, your code shall remove the line "\bibliographystyle{plain}" in order to make it work. Thanks again.

Comment: @Sissi - I have removed the line you mentioned. (I believe it may have only been necessary to get my example code working to test it with.) Thank you for accepting my answer. I greatly appreciate it! :)